# Delete Rows Based on Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete any row in a data table with a cell value in column B of "3DO" or "DOS" and shift remaining cells up.

Screenshot of data table
[image]

Workbook Name: StackOverflowTest.xlsm

Worksheet Name: Sheet1

Cell range: A1:J100000

Column with value: B

Values to search for: "3DO", "DOS"

My understanding is that the following VBA code could be altered to achieve this:

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value()
'Apply a filter to a Range and delete visible rows
'Source: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/delete-rows-cell-values/


Dim ws As Worksheet

  'Set reference to the sheet in the workbook.
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Regular Range")
  ws.Activate 'not required but allows user to view sheet if warning message appears

  'Clear any existing filters
  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  '1. Apply Filter
  ws.Range("B3:G1000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=""

  '2. Delete Rows
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Range("B4:G1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  '3. Clear Filter
  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

UPDATE:

This code from @Harun24HR seems to do the trick for me

```
Sub DelVisible()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW")

    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=3DO", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=DOS"

    ws.Range("$A$2:$J$100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

But now I'd like to add more criteria to search for in this statement and I'm unclear on how to do that. Say I am looking for "3DO", "DOS", and "Mac" for example, how would I add the "Mac" criteria in addition to this statement?

Update #2

Thanks to @user11053804 I have a working solution for looking for 3+ criteria

```
Sub RemoveOldPlatforms()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW")

    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("3DO", "All Other", "DOS", "Mac"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    ws.Range("$A$2:$J$100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What about following codes? Can you please have a try and feedback us.

```
Sub DelVisible()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Regular Range")

    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$10000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=3DO", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=DOS"

    ws.Range("$A$2:$J$10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$10000").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked well for me! Thank you @Harun24HR. How would I add more values to search and delete for in this statement? Say I wanted to look for "3DO", "DOS", and "All Other", could I modify the line like this:     ``` ws.Range("$A$1:$J$10000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=3DO", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=DOS", Operator:xIOr, Criteria3 ="=All Other" ```

Comment: Thank you again @Harun24HR, user11053804 below pointed out how to add 3+ criteria and I have updated the original post with that solution. Now I am curious how I could modify this code to delete rows that DON'T meet a criteria. For example, delete all rows that don't have the value "Dec 2018" in column G?

Answer (score 0):

Your AutoFilter statement is inadequate.

```
ws.Range("B3:B1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="EDO", Criteria2:="DOS", operator:=xlOr
```

Additional criteria would require an array with xlFilterValues.

```
ws.Range("B3:B1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=array("EDO", "DOS", "All Others"), operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: I think you mean `ws.Range("A1:J100000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="EDO", Criteria2:="DOS", operator:=xlOr`. Also they need to change `Regular Range` to `Sheet1` at the start.

Comment: If  the filter is restricted to column B then Field:=1 is appropriate. It looks like *Regular Range* is the name of the worksheet they want to work on. If it isn't I hope they could change that part themselves.

Comment: Thank you @user11053804. Field 2 worked for me and I did need to change the worksheet name (I was unclear what Regular Range was in the original code). How would I add even more condiitions to this statement? Say I wanted to look for "3DO", "DOS", and "All Other"

Comment: Thank you @Profex. Field 2 worked for me and I did need to change the worksheet name (I was unclear what Regular Range was in the original code). How would I add even more conditions to this statement? Say I wanted to look for "3DO", "DOS", and "All Other"

Comment: @TejinderMangat - See the edit made above. Note that the AutoFilter range is `B3:B1000` to use `Field:=1`.

Comment: Thank you @user11053804, and the xlFilterValues addition you added is working!

Comment: Thank you again @Profex, user11053804 pointed out how to add 3+ criteria and I have updated the original post with that solution. Now I am curious how I could modify this code to delete rows that DON'T meet a criteria. For example, delete all rows that don't have the value "Dec 2018" in column G?

Comment: Stop changing the original conditions of your question. If you have another question, then ask another question. These *' but what is I want to ...'* additions are toxic.

Comment: Fair enough @user11053804, thank you for your help and sorry for the trouble.